# Introducing JSF 1.2 in JSP / Servlet Java EE application

Tags: jsp, jsf

My environment is RAD 8, WAS 7.0.x with a lot of JSPs and Servlets.
The application also uses JAX-RPC and JAX-WS
I want to introduce JSF and start migrating some easier JSPs.

I have a huge issue that I can not migrate to JSF 2.0 straight away, because my target is WAS 7.x and I came across that it does not support JSF 2.0.
I share the WAS 7.x with other business groups. 
So I have to use JSF 1.2 for now ..

In RAD 8, I tried following:

From an testJSF.jsp file, I used c:redirect to /faces/test1.jsp.
I also tried jsp:forward to /faces/test1.jsp.
Servlet-mapping has url-pattern  entries for /faces/* and *.jsp
This time WAS 7, gave me /test1.jsp not found...

Then I tried , from testJSF.jsp file, I used c:redirect to /faces/test1.jsf
I also tried jsp:forward to /faces/test1.jsf. 
This time I also changed, Servlet-mapping with url-pattern  entries for /faces/* and *.jsf
This time WAS 7 went in an endless loop with stack overflow..

Under these environments, what should be url-pattern for servlet-mapping and how should I refer the new JSF 1.2 pages?

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with JSF 2.0 as Websphere 7.0 implements the Servlet 2.5 spec (as far as I can see).

/faces/* or *.jsf mapping should be fine, there might be a configuration problem somewhere else... you need to provide more details.

Why do you need a .jsp to test a JSF page? What happens if you open the page directly from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

> *Servlet-mapping has url-pattern entries for /faces/* and *.jsp*

You should not specify a `*.jsp` mapping for `FacesServlet`. This pattern is reserved for the servlet container's builtin `JspServlet`. This way the `FacesServlet` can never get the right JSP file to present the view.

---

> *Servlet-mapping with url-pattern entries for /faces/* and *.jsf This time WAS 7 went in an endless loop with stack overflow.*

You should not give the *actual* view file a `.jsf` extension, but a `.jsp` extension.

---

The proper setup is the following:

- Map the `FacesServlet` on alone `*.jsf`.

  ```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

  You can also use `/faces/*` instead, or add it, but this is uglier and does not allow for easy migration to JSF 2.0. So leave it away.
- The view files should have the `.jsp` extension.

  `viewid.jsp`

  ```
  <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
  <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <f:view>
      <html lang="en">
          <head>
              <title>JSF 1.2 test page</title>
          </head>
          <body>
              <h:outputText value="If you see this, JSF works!" />
          </body>
      </html>
  </f:view>
  ```
- Do not use `<c:redirect>` or `<jsp:forward>`, this makes no utter sense. Just call the page by URL directly:

  > http://localhost:8080/contextname/viewid.jsf

  Note the `.jsf` extension in the URL. This invokes the `FacesServlet`. It will then locate the `viewid.jsp` file and show it.

#### See also:

- [Coreservlets.com JSF 1.x tutorials](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf1/index.html)